# Error when printing in server with web service

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, visual-studio-2010, crystal-reports

My web service uses C# to print an invoice from the server printer. This service  works fine when called in debug mode, but after sending it to the IIS location and running the project from web explorer, I get this error:

> No printers are installed.
>
> System.Drawing.Printing.PrinterSettings.GetHdevmodeInternal(String printer) at
>   System.Drawing.Printing.PrinterSettings.GetHdevmodeInternal() at
>   System.Drawing.Printing.PrinterSettings.GetHdevmode(PageSettings
>   pageSettings) at
>   CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.PrintOptions.CopyTo(PrinterSettings
>   printer, PageSettings page)

What is the problem? The same machine will function properly in debug mode, but not in live.

This section of code throws the exception:

```
reportClass.PrintOptions.PrinterName = clsDeclaration.defultPrinter1;
reportClass.PrintToPrinter(numberOfCopies, true, 1, 1);
```

Comment: Install the device printer driver first on your server where  the system running..

Comment: yes I am already install the printer driver on the Server PC, and Like I just tell you, It's working in the debugging mode, so the driver working fine.

Comment: Check server .net framework if suitable to your project framework check also the crystal report runtime if its installed 32bit or 64 bit. check also the printer if it is connected to your server pc or check printer network.

Comment: thank you sir I got it, and the problem in the Application Pools

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the solution

The reason it works while on the development machine is that the development web service is running in the context of your windows login, which probably has the correct printers set up. On the server, it’s probably running as the Network Service or as the Local System account.

The solution is to setup printers for the system account using the instructions below. You will also need to change the identity of the application pool that your app is using to use the LocalSystem identity.

[image]